# How can I edit a linked object set in a Foundry Function?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-functions

I have an Object Type A, which has a many to many relation to Object Type B. I am trying to implement an OntologyEditFunction in TypeScript that retrieves all objects of type B that are linked to an object of type A, and then edits the returned objects. My code so far looks something like the following:

```
@OntologyEditFunction()
public async editLinkedObjects(objA: ObjectTypeA): Promise<void> {
   // Get all objects of type B that are linked to objA
    const linkedObjects = objA.objectTypeB.all();
    
   // Edit linked objects...
}
```

I noticed that the `.all()` function returns a readonly array (i.e. the return type of `linkedObjects` is a `readonly ObjectTypeB[]`). Given this, how can I modify `linkedObjects` such that I can apply edits to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `.all()` returns a readonly array, the individual objects within the returned array are not readonly. In other words, **you should still be able to iterate over linkedObjects and apply edits as you would expect!**

If for some other reason you need `linkedObjects` to be a mutable array, you can do so by creating a copy of it using ES6 array spread syntax as shown below:

```
const linkedObjectsMutable = [...linkedObjects]
```